# pandas add dataframes without NaN values in case of missing entries

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most elegant way to add two pandas DataFrames without getting NaNs in case of one missing column/row.

It is probably better described with this simple example:

```
index1 = pd.Index(["a", "b"])
data1 = np.full(shape=(2, 2), fill_value=1.0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, index=index1, columns=index1)
# df1 = 
#    a   b  
# a 1.0 1.0 
# b 1.0 1.0 

index2 = pd.Index(["b", "c"])
data2 = np.full(shape=(2, 2), fill_value=2.0)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=index2, columns=index2)
# df2 = 
#    b   c  
# b 2.0 2.0 
# c 2.0 2.0 

df = df1 + df2
```

The resulting dataframe is

```
   a   b   c 
a nan nan nan
b nan 3.0 nan
c nan nan nan
```

However, I would like it to be

```
   a   b   c 
a 1.0 1.0 nan
b 1.0 3.0 2.0
c nan 2.0 2.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with `fill_value=0`:

```
df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

output:

```
     a    b    c
a  1.0  1.0  NaN
b  1.0  3.0  2.0
c  NaN  2.0  2.0
```

documentation of the parameter:

> **fill_value**: float or None, default None
>
> Fill existing missing (NaN) values, and any new element needed for successful DataFrame alignment, with this value before computation. If
> data in both corresponding DataFrame locations is missing the result
> will be missing.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'm not allowed yet to accept your answer but will do so in few minutes